# how to prevent ASCII Encoded / Binary String SQL injection in Codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter, sql-injection

I am using CodeIgniter for two years and I am digging into penetration testing nowadays. I think that ActiveRecord does good job for preventing sql injections, but i have following questions:

1. I want to know is there any possibility of bypassing ActiveRecord's filter system by ASCII Encoded / Binary String SQL injection?
2. If it is possible, then how to prevent ASCII Encoded / Binary String SQL injection?

Comment: Do you have any  ASCII Encoded / Binary String SQL injection query.?

Comment: i am seeing some articles on google about this, i.e. http://www.bloombit.com/Articles/2008/05/ASCII-Encoded-Binary-String-Automated-SQL-Injection.aspx

Comment: I don't see anything special in there that isn't solved with regular escaping/parameterization. Furthermore it applies to .NET/MSSQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every developer have to understand one simple thing:

#### There is no NO use to separate injections by type.

While injections differ by the way they exploit the vulnerability, the cause is always the same -

#### improperly formatted query.

As long as you have your queries properly formatted, no injection ever be possible, no matter how you call it - ASCII, Blind, Time-delay, Second order, whatever.

So, just use regular Codeigniter's facilities to build a query and feel safe